# Using bootbox.confirm with .NET web forms

Tags: .net, webforms, bootbox

I am trying to work with web forms. I have basic knowledge only (I mainly work with MVC).

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" OnClientClick="return confirmItemDelete()" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' Text="Delete" OnClick="lbDeleteMessage_Click"></asp:Button>

function confirmItemDelete() {
            bootbox.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?',
                function (confirmed) {
                    return confirmed;
                });            
        };
```

Button click always causes server side Delete. This is because `bootbox.confirm` works with callbacks (return false or true only in callback). This causes always run server side postback.

What is the best solution here?

Comment: Are you familiar with WebMethods? Or, are you "allowed" to mix some MVC into the WebForms project?

Comment: I am not allowed to mix MVC. Not familiar with WebMethods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other html control for call `bootbox` and use `javascript` call `<asp:Button />` for click in callback.

**HTML**

```
<asp:Button ID="linkLogout" Style="display: none;" OnClick="linkLogout_Click" runat="server" />

<div style="padding: 3px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="showConfirm('Alert', 'Are you want to logout ?')">Logout</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function showConfirm(title, msg) {
     bootbox.confirm({
          title: title,
          message: msg,
          buttons: {
               confirm: {
                    label: 'Yes',
                    className: 'btn-primary'
               },
               cancel: {
                    label: 'No',
                    className: 'btn-default'
               }
          },
          callback: function (result) {
               if (result) {
                    $('#linkLogout').click();
               }
          }
   });
}
```